# Parabolas with Focus and Directrix - Tikz/PGF Plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am not well versed in TikZ and PGF Plots, and I am hoping someone would be able to help me with developing the structural code for a Parabola with its Focus and Directrix.

I found an image of what I am assuming was created via LaTex and was hoping to recreate this somehow. This was a perfect image of what I am looking for, because the conic sections seem to be so lost to time that I can not find good representations of this particular topic without hand drawing it.

I found a sample code for drawing a parabola, and when I attempted to recreate it, it does not let me use a fractional coefficient.

If anyone has starter code to this image, that would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gray!40,dashed] (-9,-1) grid (5,8);   % coordinate grid
        \draw[->] (-9,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};   % x-axis
        \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,8) node[above] {$y$};   % y-axis
        
        \foreach \x in {-8,...,-1,1,2,...,5}        % x-axis labels
        \draw (\x,2pt) -- (\x,-2pt) node[anchor=north, font=\footnotesize] {$\x$}; 
        
        \foreach \y in {-1,1,2,...,8}           % y-axis labels
        \draw (2pt,\y) -- (-2pt,\y) node[anchor=east, font=\footnotesize] {$\y$};
        \node at (-.3,-.3) () {$O$}; 
        \draw[<->,magenta,line width=3pt] plot[domain=-8.2:4.2,smooth,samples=101] (\x,{.125*(\x+2)^2+3});
        \draw[red,dashed,line width=1pt] (-2,-1)--(-2,8) node[pos=.9,sloped,fill=white] () {axis: $x=-2$};
        \draw[red,dashed,line width=1pt] (-9,1)--(5,1) node[pos=.8,fill=white] () {directrix: $y=1$};   
        \fill[blue] (-2,3) circle(.1) node[red,below] {\scriptsize Vertex (-2,3)};
        \fill[blue] (-2,5) circle(.1) node[red,below] {\scriptsize Focus (-2,5)};
        \node[red,fill=white] at (3,6) () {$(x+2)^2=8(y-3)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```